# What to feed to toads in India?

Tags: diet, frogs

How can I feed toad in India?

I have rescued a toad and kept in my fish tank. Now I try to feed it with fish food, but it is not eating. Please help me, what can I feed to my new baby?

Comment: Most toads/frogs eat life insects. But there are lots and lots of species commonly identified or misidentified as toads which might have other eating habits. Have you identified the species yet?

Answer (score 2):

Being a frog, it can see only things that move. So if you feed it anything which does not move, it is as if it does not exist.

In their natural environments, toads and frogs eat living (and moving) insects. Pretty much anything that moves and fits their mouths.

Therefore, you have only a few alternatives:

- buy living insects to feed to your toad;
- grow your own insects, to feed them to your toad;
- if you are in the proper area, just leave the windows open, and all the required insects will come to your toad (*worst case, I would not do that even if I would be paid loads of money*);
- release the toad to its natural environment, it has better chances of survival - *and this is the best option, in my opinion*.

---

> What to feed to toads **in India**

My best guess is that toads in India are similar enough with toads world-wide, and therefore they most likely have the same diet requirements.

Comment: to feed a toad or frog you can find earthwoms and larvae it is a bit easier than it is to feed insects that might be too fast for the toad.the best thing for any wildlife is to leave them in their natural environment.

Comment: @trondhansen: You are right. I named "insects" pretty much everything which is not an animal, bird or fish. For me, worms, larvae, centipedes and so on are also "insects", even though they do not fly.